# Permission error when trying to create a symbolic link in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm using a [Tesseract OCR flutter](https://github.com/arrrrny/tesseract_ocr) library, and the following error is thrown when the library's swift code is initializing:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to
> save the file “tessdata” in the folder “MyApp”."
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A5B1F0C-6BB3-47F1-98D3-74BF4701FB47/Runner.app/tessdata,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x282729fb0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
> "Operation not permitted"}}

By the looks of it, this happens when it's trying to create a symbolic link. Here's the code:

```
func initializeTessData() {
    
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    let destURL = documentsURL!.appendingPathComponent("tessdata")
    
    let sourceURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("tessdata")
    
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
        try fileManager.createSymbolicLink(at: sourceURL, withDestinationURL: destURL)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

[This is the causing line](https://github.com/arrrrny/tesseract_ocr/blob/7e915045c80578d05fd0172418260bea453058ad/ios/Classes/SwiftTesseractOcrPlugin.swift#L47).

I put a break point on xcode and printed `sourceURL` and `destURL` values:

> (lldb) vo sourceURL (URL) sourceURL = ▿
> file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A5B1F0C-6BB3-47F1-98D3-74BF4701FB47/Runner.app/tessdata
>
> _url : file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A5B1F0C-6BB3-47F1-98D3-74BF4701FB47/Runner.app/tessdata
> (lldb) vo destURL (URL) destURL = ▿
> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D1CAAF6E-5D63-42ED-9324-6D90FDB19447/Documents/tessdata/
>
> _url : file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D1CAAF6E-5D63-42ED-9324-6D90FDB19447/Documents/tessdata/

BTW, this error only happens on a physical iPhone. When I run it via a simulator, the error is not getting thrown.

Comment: You can not change the main bundle of your app so this will never work. You need to store that symbolic link somewhere else.

Comment: I don’t know what you need the symbolic link for so it’s hard to say. Are you sure you need it at all? Maybe it’s something you can keep in memory as a variable?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That library is using [SwiftyTesseract](https://github.com/SwiftyTesseract/SwiftyTesseract). In the tessdata folder I store the trained data files, and I guess it does this symbolic link so SwiftyTesseract will use my folder that I created in my flutter project

Comment: After a quick glans at the documentation I get the impression you should include that folder and any files as assets in your app

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I did do that. For example, in android it works, so I think I did everything correctly flutter-wise. Now I'm trying to figure out what's wrong in the Swift code of this library

Comment: I have no experience of android development or flutter so I can’t help you there. And I think this is really what this question is about.